# Laravel excel Export Queue and MultipleSheet

Tags: laravel-excel

I tried to use Laravel excel with multiple sheets and `shouldQueue`, but the file returned with an empty sheet, all the sheet created successfully though.

Comment: You may need to post, what have you tried so far.

Comment: i think the problem is with the memory size, since the file data is massive,
i manage to make a work around by limiting the sheet, instead of dumping all the record in 1 file

Answer (score 0):

I manage to make a work around by limiting the record per file

here is the code

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use App\Exports\Sheets\AnswersPerSchoolSheet;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Exportable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMultipleSheets;

class AnswersExport implements WithMultipleSheets, ShouldQueue
{
    use Exportable;

    public function __construct($start, $end)
    {
        $this->start = $start;
        $this->end = $end;
    }
    public function sheets(): array
    {
        $sheets = [];

        $schools = DB::table('schools')
            ->join('answers', 'schools.id', '=', 'answers.school_id')
            ->select('schools.id')
            ->distinct('schools.id')
            ->whereBetween('schools.id', [$this->start,$this->end])
            ->get();

        foreach ($schools as $school) {
            $sheets[] = new AnswersPerSchoolSheet($school->id);
        }

        return $sheets;
    }
}
```